# Writing the output of an SSH command to a file

Tags: perl, ssh, cpan

Using the Net::OpenSSH module, how can I connect to a host and subsequently capture/write the output of my command to a file that has been created?

This is my command:

```
ps -ef | grep jboss | grep java
```

I have the following perl script so far..

```
open PATH,">","./report/archive/rpet-$now/path.txt" or die "Unable to create file: $!";
    my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new(
                $host,
                user=>$username
                passwd=>$password
    );
    print PATH "SSH Output Would Go Here";
close PATH;
```

So what is the best way to run the command and print its output? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at the documentation (https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH)? It's in the synopsis.

```
print PATH $ssh->capture('command');
```

Though this will print any error conditions too. Capture works in both scalar and list context.

Comment: I have tried this, but it never seems to write anything to the file. Either that, or it gives me a "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host" error. Any ideas why?